# How to convert a db.collection query to a JSON one?

Tags: json, database, mongodb

I have the following query which executes well on the MONGOSH:

```
db.getCollection("user_products").aggregate( [
   {
       $lookup:
       {
         from: "users",
         localField: "user_id",
         foreignField: "_id",
         as: "user"
       }
   },
   {
       $lookup:
       {
         from: "products",
         localField: "product_id",
         foreignField: "_id",
         as: "product"
       }
   },
    {
        $unwind: "$product"
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$user"
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 1,
            "creation_date": 1,
            "support_all_payment": 1,
            "payment": 1,
            "imported": 1,
            
            "name": "$user.name",
            "country_code": "$user.country_code",
            "phone_number": "$user.phone_number",
            "wallet_credit": "$user.wallet_credit",
            "score": "$user.score",
            "birthday": "$user.birthday",
            "bio": "$user.bio",
            "education": "$user.education",
            "email": "$user.email",
            "job": "$user.job",
            "major": "$user.major",
            "sex": "$user.sex",
            "have_you_attended_courses_on_personal_and_organizational_success": "$user.have_you_attended_courses_on_personal_and_organizational_success",
            "what_books_have_you_read_about_growth_and_development_and_success": "$user.what_books_have_you_read_about_growth_and_development_and_success",
            "which_of_the_success_professors_are_you_interested_in_and_what_is_the_reason_for_your_interest": "$user.which_of_the_success_professors_are_you_interested_in_and_what_is_the_reason_for_your_interest",
            "city": "$user.city",
            "state": "$user.state",
            "favorites": "$user.favorites",
            "fixed_number": "$user.fixed_number",
            
            
            "show": "$product.show",
            "title": "$product.title",
            "type": "$product.type",
            "little_description": "$product.little_description",
            "description": "$product.description",
            "price": "$product.price",
            "support_price": "$product.support_price",
            "discount": "$product.discount",
                       
         }
    }
] )
```

Since I need to get an export of the result, and I use MongoDB Compass, then I need to convert query above to JSON formatted `{}`.

I tired some online tools with no success, any idea how can I convert it to JSON?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what your requirements are, but you could s[ave this aggregation as a view](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/views/#create-and-manage-views) and then query that (with an empty object) instead. You can see a pretty similar example [here in the docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/views/join-collections-with-view/#create-a-joined-view)

Comment: The query is already JSON-ish. Just wrap the operators in double quotes and it will make it a valid JSON.

Comment: did you check mongoexport  : https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoexport/

Comment: Also dont forget to set some bigger value for mongosh inspectDepth ( default:3 ) to avoid some nasty surprises in the output ... :) -> https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/reference/configure-shell-settings-global/#behavior-with-config-api

Comment: By @R2D2 "inspectDepth", do you mean "allies" ?

Comment: @MartinAJ : Check the link for details , in case you print  out to file from mongosh if you have inspectDepth = 1 , none of nested objects will be expanded ...

Answer (score 1):

If that query works in `mongosh` and you're using `mongosh` then you don't need Compass to export the output as JSON.  Assume your query is in a file named `q1.js`, something like this:

```
cursor = db.getCollection("user_products").aggregate([ ... ]}
```

then just call `JSON.stringify()` on the output to emit proper JSON:

```
cursor.forEach(function(doc) {
    print(JSON.stringify(doc));
});
```

or, to preserve type fidelity (at the expense of a more complicated output structure), use EJSON:

```
    print(EJSON.stringify(doc));
```

and run the query from the command line:

```
$  mongosh --quiet mongodb://whereever/dbName q1.js > theOutput.json
```